# MySql request returns duplicates on LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

3 tables

```
table: people 

id name 
1  john  
2  Mike
3  Sam  
4  Andy
```

-

```
table goods:

   g_id g_name  g_class
    1   sugar  food
    2   salt   food
    3   boat   transp
    4   house  habitation
    5   car    transp
```

-

```
   table goods_owned:
      go_id person_id   good_id
        1   3           3
        2   3           1
        3   3           5
        4   2           4
        5   1           2
```

Now when i select

```
SELCT people.id, people.name, goods.name
   FROM people
      LEFT JOIN goods_owned ON goods_owned.person_id = people.id
      LEFT JOIN goods ON goods.g_id = goods_owned.good_id
         WHERE people.id = 3
```

Then in response it duplicates entry's from table "people":

```
1, Mike, boat
1, Mike, sugar
1, Mike, car
```

Is there way to build request to get:

```
1, Mike, boat, sugar, car
```

Comment: search `pivot+mysql` and you'll find your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, look at [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), which collects all the values for each `GROUP BY` and comma-separates them.

```
SELCT people.id, people.name, GROUP_CONCAT(goods.name)
FROM people
LEFT JOIN goods_owned ON goods_owned.person_id = people.id
LEFT JOIN goods ON goods.g_id = goods_owned.good_id
WHERE people.id = 3
GROUP BY people.id
```

Comment: Gr8 thanks. However it does output one dimensional array with all "boat, sugar, car" as one key not separate.

Comment: +1.  Be aware of the maximum length returned by GROUP_CONCAT, and the error that is returned if `group_concat_max_len` is exceeded.

Comment: Sorry @JohnA, I assumed that was what you wanted. You *aren't* able to put each of "boat", "sugar", "car" in a separate column each unless you know in advance exactly how many values will come out (so in your example there were 3) - this is called a pivot table and MySQL doesn't support it (better to do it on the code side than the MySQL side).